# JPA - Hibernate - Pagination - Data Transfer Size

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA with Hibernate as the provider. I noticed that "select top n" query is used for pagination -- to get records 990 to 1000, 'select top 1000' query is issued to the database. Is all data for rows 1 to 1000 transferred on to the client? (database and application servers are on different physical servers). How do I measure the amount of data (in bytes) transferred between database and application server?

Answer (score 0):

The translation to SQL depends on the database dialect. Using Oracle, for example, only the requested rows are selected. Hibernate uses `ResultSet.absolute()` (if possible) to directly go to the 990th row when it can't select only the 10 wanted rows. Debug the Loader.doQuery method to inspect what Hibernate is doing with your database.